# How do I only update rows in table A with the data which has changed in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm inserting data into table A. After a few days have past the data in the Table A might be out of date from the live system.

What I want to do is load the rows that would have changed from the live system into say a temp table and update only the rows which have to corresponding GUID to update with the correct data.

I need help with how the update statement should be formatted.

Comment: Did u try something we can help on that to fix?

Comment: You need to provide more information such as tables and anything you've already attempted. If you have a date of entry for the data in the table then what you're asking for can be done rather simply.

Comment: Look for MERGE statement.

Answer (score 0):

This would update only the **column name** Table A with **column name** of TableB  with UID matches on both table: Give a try

```
update set a.name=b.name from TestA a INNER JOIN TestB b on a.UID=b.UID;
```